# How to sort array controller alphabetically with numbers last in objective-c?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, sorting, nssortdescriptor

I have an `NSArrayController` and I would like to sort the contents so that anything with English alphabets are sorted first and then anything with numbers and non English characters are sorted last.

For example: A, B , C ... Z, 1 , 2, 3 ... 9, 구, 결, ...

Currently I only know how to sort items in alphabetical order. Suggestions?

```
NSSortDescriptor *sort = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"name" ascending:YES];
        [dataController setSortDescriptors: [NSArray arrayWithObject: sort]];
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `sortedArrayUsingComparator` to customize the sort algorithm to your needs. For instance, you can give precedence to symbols with this lines:

```
NSArray *assorted = [@"1 2 3 9 ; : 구 , 결 A B C Z ! á" componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];
NSArray *sorted = [assorted sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id obj1, id obj2) {
    /* NSOrderedAscending, NSOrderedSame, NSOrderedDescending */
    BOOL isPunct1 = [[NSCharacterSet punctuationCharacterSet] characterIsMember:[(NSString*)obj1 characterAtIndex:0]];
    BOOL isPunct2 = [[NSCharacterSet punctuationCharacterSet] characterIsMember:[(NSString*)obj2 characterAtIndex:0]];
    if (isPunct1 && !isPunct2) {
        return NSOrderedAscending;
    } else if (!isPunct1 && isPunct2) {
        return NSOrderedDescending;
    }
    return [(NSString*)obj1 compare:obj2 options:NSDiacriticInsensitiveSearch|NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];         
}];
```

To put *English* characters before *non-English* ones, it'd be enough to use `NSDiacriticInsensitiveSearch | NSCaseInsensitiveSearch` as options, no fancy algorithm required.

If you need to support iOS without blocks try `sortedArrayUsingSelector`.

Answer (score 5):

Another solution by testing, if a string is latin1-encodeable:

- test for both strings, if the first character is a latin (aka english) character
- if both are, test if both starts either with a letter or a number. In both cases, leave it up the `compare:`
- else, if one starts with the number and one with a letter, `return NSOrderingAscending`, if the one with letter its first, otherwise `NSOrderingDescending`
- If both strings aren't latin, let `compare:` decide again
- if one is latin, and one not, `return NSOrderingAscending` if the latin is first, otherwise `NSOrderingDescending`

the code

```
NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"peach",@"apple",@"7",@"banana",@"ananas",@"5", @"papaya",@"4",@"구",@"결",@"1" ,nil];

array = [array sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id obj1, id obj2) {
    NSString *s1 = [obj1 substringToIndex:1];
    NSString *s2 = [obj2 substringToIndex:1];
    BOOL b1 = [s1 canBeConvertedToEncoding:NSISOLatin1StringEncoding];
    BOOL b2 = [s2 canBeConvertedToEncoding:NSISOLatin1StringEncoding];

    if ((b1 == b2) && b1) {//both number or latin char
        NSRange r1 = [s1 rangeOfCharacterFromSet:[NSCharacterSet decimalDigitCharacterSet]];
        NSRange r2 = [s2 rangeOfCharacterFromSet:[NSCharacterSet decimalDigitCharacterSet]];
        if (r1.location == r2.location ) { // either both start with a number or both with a letter
            return [obj1 compare:obj2 options:NSDiacriticInsensitiveSearch|NSCaseInsensitiveSearch]; 
        } else {  // one starts wit a letter, the other with a number
            if ([s1 rangeOfCharacterFromSet:[NSCharacterSet decimalDigitCharacterSet]].location == NSNotFound) {
                return NSOrderedAscending;
            }
            return NSOrderedDescending;
        }
    } else if((b1 == b2) && !b1){ // neither latin char
        return [obj1 compare:obj2 options:NSDiacriticInsensitiveSearch|NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];
    } else { //one is latin char, other not
        if (b1) return NSOrderedAscending;
        return NSOrderedDescending;
    }

}];
for (NSString *s in array) NSLog(@"%@", s);
```

**result**

```
ananas
apple
banana
papaya
peach
1
4
5
7
구
결
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you can do that kind of sorting without defining your own comparison function.

To this aim, you could use [sortedArrayUsingFunction](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSArray/sortedArrayUsingFunction%3acontext%3a):

```
[array sortedArrayUsingFunction:f context:userContext];
```

where f is defined as:

```
NSInteger f(id num1, id num2, void *context)
{
   int v1 = [num1 intValue];
   int v2 = [num2 intValue];
   if (...)
     return NSOrderedAscending;
   else if (...)
     return NSOrderedDescending;
   else
     return NSOrderedSame;
}
```

If you prefer not creating function for doing this you could use the block-version of the method, [sortedArrayUsingComparator](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSArray/sortedArrayUsingComparator%3a):

```
[array sortedArrayUsingComparator: ^(id obj1, id obj2) {
                                             return NSOrderedSame;
                                   }];
```

Answer (score 1):

A sort descriptor based on a comparator should do the trick (note: not tested).

```
NSComparator cmp = ^(id str1, id str2) {

// Make your sorting
    if ( /* str1 before str2 */ )
    return NSOrderedAscending
    else if ( /* str2 after str1 */ )
    return NSOrderedDescending
    else 
    return NSOrderedSame
};

NSSortDescriptor *sd = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey: sortKey ascending: YES comparator: cmp];

NSArrayController *ac = // ...

[ac setSortDescriptor: sd];
```

You of course have to define your own sort order algorithm - but this example should show how to use a sort descriptor for an array controller.

Answer (score 0):

One thing is missing to answer properly to the question : NSNumericSearch

```
NSArray *assorted = [@"1 2 3 9 ; : 구 , 결 A B C Z ! á" componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];
NSArray *sorted = [assorted sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id obj1, id obj2) {
    /* NSOrderedAscending, NSOrderedSame, NSOrderedDescending */
    BOOL isPunct1 = [[NSCharacterSet punctuationCharacterSet] characterIsMember:[(NSString*)obj1 characterAtIndex:0]];
    BOOL isPunct2 = [[NSCharacterSet punctuationCharacterSet] characterIsMember:[(NSString*)obj2 characterAtIndex:0]];
    if (isPunct1 && !isPunct2) {
        return NSOrderedAscending;
    } else if (!isPunct1 && isPunct2) {
        return NSOrderedDescending;
    }
    return [(NSString*)obj1 compare:obj2 options:NSDiacriticInsensitiveSearch|NSCaseInsensitiveSearch|NSNumericSearch]|;         
}];
```