# Sorting alphabetically with numbers at the beginning

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I have an array values like this: {apple, queen, microsoft, 50cent}. I want to sort the array alphabetical order and 50cent at the end. I'm doing with the following method but it sort the 50cent on top:

```
[albums sortUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:
                                  [[[NSSortDescriptor alloc] 
                                    initWithKey:@"name" 
                                    ascending:YES 
                                    selector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)] 
                                   autorelease]]];
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8242735/how-to-sort-array-controller-alphabetically-with-numbers-last-in-objective-c

Answer (score 5):

You could use [comparator blocks](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

In your case, the block should do following:

- check the first letter of the two strings, are they both numbers or letter, do `return [obj1 compare:obj2]`
- if the first objects starts with a number but the second with a letter, `return NSOrderedAscending`, if it is the other way around, `return NSOrderedDescending`

to get the first letter, use `[obj1 substringToIndex:1]`

---

the complete code of this idea:

```
NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"peach",@"apple",@"banana",@"ananas",@"50cents", @"papaya", nil];

array = [array sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id obj1, id obj2) {
    NSString *s1 = [obj1 substringToIndex:1];
    NSString *s2 = [obj2 substringToIndex:1];

    if ([s1 rangeOfCharacterFromSet:[NSCharacterSet decimalDigitCharacterSet]].location == [s2 rangeOfCharacterFromSet:[NSCharacterSet decimalDigitCharacterSet]].location) {
        return  [obj1 compare:obj2];
    } else {
        if ([s1 rangeOfCharacterFromSet:[NSCharacterSet decimalDigitCharacterSet]].location == NSNotFound) {
            return NSOrderedAscending;
        }
    }
    return  NSOrderedDescending;
}];
```

As you use `sortUsingDescriptors:`, you must be using NSMutableArray. You can use in-place ordering with comparators with `sortUsingComparator:`.

```
[array sortUsingBlock:<The block stays the same>];
```